# Django Reset Loop in Template

Tags: python, django

How to reset loop (e.g. if a category change, reset the counter for sub category) in Django template?

1. Game
   1.1. Cricket
   1.2. Football
   1.3. Base Ball
2. Pets
   2.1. Dog
   2.2. Cat
   2.3. Fish

NB: ***forloop.counter*** can't reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use loop naming inside templates. This is especially useful for your case of nested loops.

Say you have the following sections structure :

```py
{
    "sections": [
       {
          "name": "Game",
          "subsections": [
             "Cricket",
             "Football",
             "Base Ball"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name": "Pets",
          "subsections": [
             "Dog",
             "Cat",
             "Fish"
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

You can name loops (outer and inner loops) and thus have independent loop indexes.

```py
{% for section in sections %}
    {% set outer_loop = loop %}
    {{ outer_loop.index }}. {{ section.name }}
    {% for subsection in section.subsections %}
        {% set inner_loop = loop %}
        {{ outer_loop.index }}.{{ inner_loop.index }}. {{ subsection }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This produces the following output :

```
••••
••••1.•Game
••••
••••••••
••••••••1.1.•Cricket
••••
••••••••
••••••••1.2.•Football
••••
••••••••
••••••••1.3.•Base•Ball
••••

••••
••••2.•Pets
••••
••••••••
••••••••2.1.•Dog
••••
••••••••
••••••••2.2.•Cat
••••
••••••••
••••••••2.3.•Fish
••••
```